# Galaxy S II - USB debugging not turning off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II. Instead of [Samsung Kies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies), I have installed [MyPhoneExplorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyPhoneExplorer) to use for synchronization. This required me to enable USB debugging.

After I turn it off and connect Kies again, it still tells me I am in the wrong mode. Please note that:

- I have made several tries, with reboot(s)
- Even with debug off, when I connect a cable I get the "USB storage" screen
- the only running processes are those that I cannot kill (system processes and some watchdogs, that existed while I could connect).
- If I try to run MyPhoneExplorer again, it will then complain that no device is connected to USB (so Kies thinks I have USB debug on, and MyPhoneExplorer that I have it off...)

Is there a solution?

Comment: have you tried to reinstall MyPhoneExplorer?